# Save toggle state of mat slide toggle

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using slide-toggle in a aproject.However I am unbale to save the toggled stae.Everytime I refresh the page,the slide toggle returns to default state instead of remaining in the toggled state.I'm new to angular and don't know what to do.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Here is the ts code:

```
export class ToggleComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output()
  change: EventEmitter<MatSlideToggleChange> ;
  @Input()
checked: Boolean 
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  isChecked = true;
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  filteringSchedule: boolean ;
  toggle:Boolean;

  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = formBuilder.group({
      enableWifi: false,
      acceptTerms: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
    });
  }

  onFormSubmit(formValue: any) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(formValue, null, 2));
  }

  onChange(ob: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    this.filteringSchedule=!this.filteringSchedule;
    console.log(!this.filteringSchedule);
  } 
}
```

The template code:

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(formGroup.value)" ngNativeValidate>
  <mat-action-list>
    <mat-list-item > <mat-slide-toggle  (change)="onChange($event)"  [checked]="filteringSchedule"  formControlName="enableWifi" >Enable Wifi</mat-slide-toggle></mat-list-item> 
    <mat-list-item > <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="acceptTerms">Accept Terms of Service</mat-slide-toggle></mat-list-item>
</mat-action-list>
  <p>Form Group Status: {{ formGroup.status}}</p>

  <button mat-rasied-button type="submit">Save Settings</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try with local storage

Comment: Can you give me a example.I'm sorry,I've just started angular.

Comment: check the posted answer\

Answer (score 0):

Store your toggle property in `localStorage` and then you can retrieve `localStorage` value on `ngOnInit` method.

You can even use `sessionStorage` based on your requirement. Use of `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` is almost identical, you just need to replace one with another.

```
onChange(ob: MatSlideToggleChange) {
  this.filteringSchedule = !this.filteringSchedule;
  localStorage.setItem('yourKey', JSON.stringify(this.filteringSchedule));
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.filteringSchedule = localStorage.getItem('yourKey') == 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Web storages** can be used to retain the state of the toggle button (toggled button doesn't change on the page refresh).

Here I've made a [**Working Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toggle-button-local-storage) with the code you have provided for your app. I've used local-storage to achieve the desired feature.

Your ToggleComponent is updated below:-

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSlideToggleChange } from '@angular/material';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toggle',
  templateUrl: './toggle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toggle.component.css']
})
export class ToggleComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() change: EventEmitter<MatSlideToggleChange>;
  @Input() checked: boolean;

  isChecked = true;
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  filteringSchedule: boolean;
  toggle: boolean;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteringSchedule = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('toggleButtonState'));
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      enableWifi: this.filteringSchedule,
      acceptTerms: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
    });
  }

  onFormSubmit(formValue: any) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(formValue, null, 2));
  }

  onChange(ob: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    this.filteringSchedule = !this.filteringSchedule;
    localStorage.setItem('toggleButtonState', JSON.stringify(this.filteringSchedule));
  }
}
```

Also note:- To be consistent for the user across all browsers in addition (or instead of) to storing toggled state of the button in cookies/local storage you can store it server side and when loading the site get the info about the toggled button state from the server.

*On a side note form builder code, you have placed inside the constructor should be kept inside `ngOnInit`, to avoid performance issues with the app.*

Hope this is helpful.